# How to turn off reminder for a time period in android calender?

Tags: android

From my application, i want to turn off the reminder for a time period (Suppose 10PM to 6AM). I mean in this time period, user should not get any reminder. How can i do this?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Really is there no way?? No one is giving answer. Presently i am solving this by making the notification sound as silent.